# What's difference between property and fields of meta in django form?

Tags: django, django-forms

Curious about their difference. Example :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', '남'),
    ('F', '여'),
)


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(
        years=range(1970, 2015)), required=True)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, initial='M')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'birth', 'email',
                  'gender', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.birthday = self.cleaned_data['birth']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

It defines `email`, `birth`, `gender` as properties of form, and it also has `fields` in `Class Meta`. I want to clearly understand their difference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Meta.fields` property is for [model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/). It is used to specify which model fields you want the model form to handle. So if you had a model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

You could define a form that only handles the `name`, because the `date` is auto-populated and you might not want the user to be able to set it manually:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['name']
```

This property is not used on regular (non-model) forms.

The form in your question subclasses `UserCreationForm` which is a `ModelForm` for the `User` model. So the `fields` property is specifying which of the `User` model properties you want the form to expose.

The field definitions on the class itself (`email`, `birth`, `gender`) are only necessary if:

1. You want to add fields to the form that are not in the model. In this case, it looks like `gender` and `birth` are exactly such fields (unless you have a custom user model which has these fields).
2. You want to customise the widget used to render a field. In this case you can override the original field and specify a custom widget. This is what is being done in the `birth` field where the widget has a restricted date range that would not exist in the default widget.

All the other fields (`username`, `email`) will be rendered using the default widgets because you haven't explicitly specified them in the class. `password1` and `password2` are not `User` model properties but are additional fields defined in the `UserCreationForm`.